# How to bookmark favourite tags and related tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, bookmarks

I have searched a lot about favorite tags, and well understood how it works. I have had been following Stack Overflow religiously, and my focus has always been to help the community with a good answer to the questions, specifically to the questions tagged with `oracle`.

I have bookmarked the page with questions having "oracle" tag. Thus, I could easily see the page with all the questions tagged as "oracle". However, I need to manually search for questions tagged with "oracle 10g", "11g" etc. Basically, the synonyms.

I have tried my best to bookmark a page which would have all Oracle related questions, unfortunately, I could only see the possible way to use favorite tags. But, how to bookmark it?

I apologize, if a wiki/explanation already exists. But, as a regular contributor, it will be very useful to me to have a page bookmarked to see the new questions related to Oracle.

I am new to meta stackexchange, so moderators/community fellow members, please feel free to edit my question, if you think it would make it more explicit, especially the tags.

I regularly visit many forums, and I very well know "SO" is **NOT** a forum. But, what I find difficult is, all other forums where I am either a "moderator" or an active contributor, it is quite easy to get to the questions related to a specific technology. As all the questions would reside in one sub-forum. But, I can't get such ease in SO.  Hope I make sense.

Comment: You don't have to bookmark, Stack Exchange portal got Filtered Questions option. Here is the filter you need: http://stackexchange.com/filters/141166/oracle-questions

Comment: Thanks, the filter looks neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want to search for

```
[oracle*]
```

?

So [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle*%5D) :) (and bookmark this address if you want)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Yes, oracle as a tag. If, oracle is the mandatory tag, then I could easily find all related questions about `sql`, `plsql` etc.

Comment: Great, than you. But, how to include the `OR` for the tags? So that, I can have the page with any question with `oracle` tag as well as all it's synonyms. Once again, thanks.

Comment: @Lalit it works this way already...

Comment: Looks fine. Even the filter does the same thing, it doesn't show up all the tags, looks neat. Anyway, I am going to bookmark the link given by you.